# Erro de Ponto Flutuante

Tags: delphi, arredondamento

Segue o código do **preço total** que está dando o erro de ponto flutuante`:

```
//Pr. Total
sgItens.Cells[5,l] := FormatFloat('###,###,###,##0.00',StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 210, 14)));
cont:=  StrToFloat(sgItens.Cells[5,l]);
valorTotal:= valorTotal+cont;
```

Estou tentando adquirir um certo valor para obter o `troco` da subtração de duas variáveis:

Segue abaixo o código do **valor Pago**:

```
//Valor Pago
sgFinalizadoras.Cells[3,l] := FormatFloat('##,###,##0.00',StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 80, 13)));
valorPago:=  StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 80, 13));
```

E logo abaixo o código para realizar a subtração, no caso seria a função matemática do **troco** e algumas das linhas do `StringGrid`, esta dando erro de ponto flutuante:

```
//Troco
troco:= valorPago - valorTotal;
Edit2.Text := FormatFloat('##,###,##0.00',troco);
```

Em que eu estaria errando?

Comment: Teria como postar qual erro está ocorrendo? Uma descrição, e possivelmente a linha do erro?

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn, no caso seria um erro de ponto Flutuante, que ficou assim.. "'Valor' is not a valid floating point value". Esta dando este erro no valor total.

Comment: Desculpe, mas ainda não consegui compreender em qual linha pode estar o erro. Só pela descrição, me parece um erro de "," e ".".... Mas, estou chutando, aqui :)

Comment: Sem problemas @carlosrafaelgn, eu achei o problema de ponto flutuante, ele estava tentando converter um valor em string, e não estava dando certo, porem o valor era em centavos, o único valor que eu deveria converter é o valor "TROCO"!, o restante eu deveria dividir e encontrar o valor correto, ou seja, Unidade= "Dividir por 1000" e Preço= "Dividir por 100". Mas obrigado pela atenção!!

Comment: Sem problemas! :)

Comment: Só um adendo: Você não precisa fazer `FormatFloat('##,###,##0.00',troco)`, basta fazer `FormatFloat(',0.00',troco)` que ele vai colocar cada separado de milhar em seu devido lugar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `StrtoFloat` vai aceitar uma `string` da seguinda forma:

```delphi
StrToFloat('9999,99');  // --> Assim é aceito
```

Já, dessa forma ocorre o erro de ponto flutuante:

```delphi
StrToFloat('9999.99');  // --> Assim NÃO é aceito
```

Uma outra forma da qual não é aceito é assim:

```delphi
StrToFloat('9.999,99');  // --> Assim NÃO é aceito
```

Nesse último, apesar do caracter separador de decimais ser a vírgula como no primeiro exemplo em que ele é aceito, há também o ponto de separação de milhar. Dessa forma não é aceito.

Então em seu exemplo você obtém um valor em `string` e o converte em `double`, já formatando para se tornar apresentável com `FormatFloat`:

```delphi
sgItens.Cells[5,l] := FormatFloat('###,###,###,##0.00',StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 210, 14)));
```

O que, dependendo do valor, pode se tornar em algo como: `99.999,99`.

Ao tentar transformar esse valor `string` em um double novamente você já atropela o terceiro exemplo que mostrei sobre o `StrToFloat` e então recebe a `Exception`.

```delphi
cont := StrToFloat(sgItens.Cells[5,l]);
```

O que não ocorreria se você fizesse algo como:

```delphi
//Pr. Total
cont := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 210, 14));
valorTotal := valorTotal+cont;

sgItens.Cells[5,l] := FormatFloat('###,###,###,##0.00', cont);
```